# What equation represents a line that is parallel to the line $y=-4x+5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

What equation represents a line that is parallel to the line $y=-4x+5$ ?

Oh and how do you find a equation that is parallel to a line?

Answer (score 5):

In order to be parallel to your line, a line has to have the same **slope** as your line. So it has to have slope $-4$.

Thus any line parallel to the line $y=-4x+5$ has an equation of the form $y=-4x+b$, where $b$ is any number.